# simple quote escape issue with pdo-php-javascript (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, quotes

here is my problem :

i get a string back from my database with PDO in a php script (called in an ajax query) :

```
...some code
$myString = $pdoObject['field'];
...some code
```

The string contains one single quote : '

```
example :
          it's strange
```

later in this php script i put the string into a long string variable that i send back to my ajax query :

```
$wholeString = "<tr><td><span title='$myString'>Some Text</span></td></tr>";
```

then i send it back : 
    json_encode($wholeString);

in my ajax query i just put the result into a jquery field :

```
...some code
success : function(response){
    $("#myField").html(response);
}
...some code
```

the TITLE thing is always cutted at the quote :

```
<tr><td><span title='it'>Some Text</span></td></tr>
```

if i try to use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars before i put $myString into $wholeString, it does not change anything... there is something i miss somewhere...

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have an html injection problem. You need to use htmlspecialchars() to escape ALL of the html metachars in your text, which includes `'`

e.g.

```
$wholeString = "<tr><td><span title='" . htmlspecialchars($myString, ENT_QUOTES) . "'>Some Text</span></td></tr>";
```

As written in your code, you'd be generating:

```
<tr><td><span title='It's strange'>Some text etc...
```

which would cause the browser to parse the span tag as

```
<span
   title='It'    // attribute "title" with value "It"
   s             // unknown random attribute s
   strange'      // unknown random attribute "strange" with illegal single-quote
```

Comment: yeah, i'm ok with your answer, BUT, in my code, if i replace '$myString' by '".htmlspecialchars($myString)."' the result is exactly the same... nothing changes

Comment: ah, doh.. sorry. forgot that specialchars doesn't do `'` by default. you have to use `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem :) (i can only accept answer within a few minutes and i have to go, i'll do it soon ;) )